# Grabing values from one file (via awk) and using them in another (via sed)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, gawk, distinct-values

I am moving using gawk to grab some values but not all values from a file. I have another file that's a template that I will use to replace certain piece then generate a file specific to those values I grab. I would like to use sed to substitute these fields of interest that are in the template.

```
  the dog NAME , likes to ACTION in water when he's bored
```

another file,f1, would have the name of the dog and the action

```
   Maxs,swim
   StoneCold,digs
   Thor,leaps
```

So I can grab these values and store them into an associative array...what I cant do, or see, is how do I get these to my sed script?
so a simple sed script could be like this

```
s/NAME/ value from f1
s/ACTION/ value from f1
```

so my out put for the template would be

```
  the dog Maxs , likes to swim in water when he's bored
```

So if I ran a bash file, the command would look something like this, or what I have attempted

```
    gawk -f f1 animalNameAction | sed -f (is there a way to put something here) template | cat

       gawk -f f1 animalNameAction > PulledValues| sed -f PulledValues template | cat
```

but none of this has worked. So I am left wondering how this could be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, using `awk` itself,

I assume, template can be of multiline char,

- so in `FNR==NR{}` block, I saved entire file (template) contents in variable `t`,
- and in other block, I replaced `NAME` and `ACTION` with first and second fields from comma separated file.

**Here is example :**

```
$ cat template 
the dog NAME , likes to ACTION in water when he's bored

$ cat file 
Maxs,swim
StoneCold,digs
Thor,leaps

$ awk 'FNR==NR{ t = (t ? t RS :"") $0; next}{ s=t; gsub(/NAME/,$1,s); gsub(/ACTION/,$2,s); print s}' template FS=',' file 
the dog Maxs , likes to swim in water when he's bored
the dog StoneCold , likes to digs in water when he's bored
the dog Thor , likes to leaps in water when he's bored
```

Better Readable :

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ 
              t = (t ? t RS :"") $0; 
              next
     }
     {  
         s=t; 
         gsub(/NAME/,$1,s); 
         gsub(/ACTION/,$2,s); 
         print s
     }
     ' template FS=',' file
```